# How much data is included in Disc Image?

Tags: windows, images

Does creating a Windows disk image copy the entire disk, or just the data contained within the OS, plus user data?  That is, only the bits on the disk that are referenced by the master file table (if I understand correctly).  I know there are ways to completely copy every bit on a disk, so I'm wondering if disk image does this or only copies actual files.  Sorry if this has been asked already.

Comment: What kind of image?

Comment: An image used to backup or restore the OS, plus all user files

Comment: And how are you producing this image?

Comment: In Windows 10: 
Control Panel\System and Security\Backup and Restore (Windows 7)
then Create System Image

Answer (score -1):

A Windows disk image backup will copy the entire disk and can be used to restore it
entirely. The only part it cannot restore is the disk signature, found in the very
first bytes of the disk and initialized by Device Manager.

This is distinct from a partition backup, which will only backup the contents
of one partition, although in some backup products this difference is not so
evident.
According to a comment below, it seems like Windows Backup has lost the
ability to do a real image backup that it had years ago.

I recommend to avoid using the deprecated Windows Backup, since it is being
officially discontinued and has too many gotchas.
Use a third-party product instead.

See the article
[Best Free Drive Cloning Software](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-cloning-software.htm)
for a list of such free products with reviews, where
my personal favorite is AOMEI Backupper.
You should choose a product that has boot media, create that media, and test
that it can see the disk containing the backups, just in case.

Comment: This doesn't seem to match the actual "system image backup" behavior, e.g. [in this screenshot](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/xwib_4.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+ws+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.5l7q9TuJxI.png) the backup's size is apparently _only_ the data used by files – which would imply that it's not an 100% block copy.

Comment: @grawity: I haven't used Windows Backup for years and don't know its current capabilities. I do know that I have encountered here often enough users who trusted it and lost their data. So all I do is counsel against using it. As Microsoft is currently phasing it out, I think it should be avoided.

Comment: Those „System Image“ Backups are VHD (Virtual Disk) Files. The backup program is filesystem aware (it can exclude files). For efficiency reasons it also only copies allocated blocks. However I am not sure how strict it is. It might copy single blocks inbetween two allocated blocks or it might always copy complete clusters (including unallocated slack). If you want to be sure it is probably better to use WIM images with DISM tool. There is a tool/script which helps with that, but it’s from a German computer magazine: https://www.heise.de/ct/artikel/c-t-WIMage-3863074.html#nav_so_funktioniert__1